# Find the height of liquid in a partially filled upsidedown cone knowing the full height, diameter/radius at top, and volume of liquid in the cone.

Tags: volume

[image: Image of cone.]

I can't for the life of me figure out how to calculate the height of water in a partially filled cone if I know the cone's full height, radius at top, and volume of water in the cone.

d = 92 cm
h = 33 cm
v = 36.64590267 Litres
x = ?

Please help!

Comment: The volumes of similar figures are in the same ratio as the cubes of corresponding lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw the perpendicular to the base from the vertex of the cone. The radius at the top is $R=d/2$. The radius at $x$ is $r$. You have similar triangles, so you can find $r$ in terms of $x$, $h$, and $R$. Now write the volume of the liquid in terms of $x$. Can you take it from here?

**EDIT**

Similar triangles: $$\frac hR=\frac xr$$
So $$r=\frac{Rx}h$$
The volume of the liquid in the cone is $$V=\frac13\pi r^2x=\frac13\pi \frac{R^2}{h^2}x^3=\frac{\pi d^2}{12h^2}x^3$$
Therefore $$x=\sqrt[3]{\frac{12Vh^2}{\pi d^2}}$$

Comment: I'm confused on how I'm to find r at the top of the liquid if I don't know the height of the liquid?

Comment: You write it in terms of $x$. Then when you write the volume of the liquid, you will have an expression that depends only on $x$.

Comment: I thank you for your help, but, math really isn't my thing.  I'm a programmer trying to calculate this height using code.   I would be eternally grateful if you could just provide me with the equation?   I'm not a student cheating on school work :)  I'm a 45 year old dude just trying to find an equation.

Comment: I've added the derivation

Comment: Thank you so much!  I added this formula to my program and it works perfectly.   You are a lifesaver!